# Modify CRC64's hash table to generate 65536 instead of 256 values

Tags: c, hash, cryptography, crc

Simply modifying the 256 in the loop to 65536 just repeats the same 256 values over and over again. How to generate 65536 different values?

```
#define CRC64_ECMA182_POLY 0x42F0E1EBA9EA3693ULL

static uint64_t crc64_table[256] = {0};

static void generate_crc64_table(void)
{
    uint64_t i, j, c, crc;

    for (i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        crc = 0;
        c = i << 56;

        for (j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            if ((crc ^ c) & 0x8000000000000000ULL)
                crc = (crc << 1) ^ CRC64_ECMA182_POLY;
            else
                crc <<= 1;
            c <<= 1;
        }

        crc64_table[i] = crc;
    }
}
```

Comment: You also need to update the `crc64_table[256]` to `crc64_table[65536]`... not to mention that `c = i << 56` leaves you with only 8 bits of data (and you will need more), so consider `c = i << 48`.

Comment: [XY Problem](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=542341)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want 65536 values, presumably you want a 16 bit table, so upgrade the bit loop to 16 as well.

```
static void generate_crc64_table(void)
{
    uint64_t i, j, c, crc;

    for (i = 0; i < 65536 ; i++) { // 65536 was 256  
        crc = 0;
        c = i << 32; // 32 was 56

        for (j = 0; j < 16; j++) { // 16 was 8
            if ((crc ^ c) & 0x8000000000000000ULL)
                crc = (crc << 1) ^ CRC64_ECMA182_POLY;
            else
                crc <<= 1;
            c <<= 1;
        }

        crc64_table[i] = crc;
    }
}
```

no guarantees that this will produce a useful table, but the values should all be different at-least.

Comment: Modify the 32 to 48 and it will produce all unique numbers. (I checked.) Thanks!

Comment: @Keisuke - if the processor is little endian, you'll need to compensate.

Answer (score 0):

If the generated CRC is supposed to match bit or byte oriented CRC on a little endian processor, such as X86, you need to swap upper/lower bytes of each 2 byte == 16 bit pair. Example code, not sure if this could be cleaned up. Note that *len* in the generate function is # shorts == # 2 byte elements == # 16 bit elements.

```
#define CRC64_ECMA182_POLY 0x42F0E1EBA9EA3693ULL

static uint64_t crc64_table[65536] = {0};

static void generate_crc64_table(void)
{
    uint64_t i, j, crc;
    for (i = 0; i < 65536; i++) {
        crc = i << 48;
        for (j = 0; j < 16; j++) 
            // assumes two's complement math
            crc = (crc << 1) ^ ((0ull-(crc>>63))&CRC64_ECMA182_POLY);
        // swap byte pairs on index and values for table lookup
        crc64_table[((i & 0xff00) >> 8) | ((i & 0x00ff) << 8)] = 
            ((crc & 0xff00ff00ff00ff00ull) >> 8) | ((crc & 0x00ff00ff00ff00ffull) << 8);
    }
}

static uint64_t generate_crc64(uint16_t *bfr, int len)
{
    uint64_t crc = 0;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
        // generates crc with byte pairs swapped
        crc = crc64_table[(crc>>48) ^ *bfr++] ^ (crc << 16);
        // unswap byte pairs for return
    return ((crc & 0xff00ff00ff00ff00) >> 8) | ((crc & 0x00ff00ff00ff00ff) << 8);
}
```